# Unable to run manage.py on codeship

Tags: python, django, codeship

I've been trying to build my django project using Codeship, as describe here: [Codeship Blog](https://blog.codeship.com/django-continuous-integration-bitbucket-dotcloud/).

These are my setup commands:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py runserver
tar -czf release-backend.tgz .*
```

My requirements.txt contains `Django==1.8.0`

However, when run on codeship, build fails giving the error:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: can you list your directory structure? 
I assume that you did execute "django-admin startproject <yoursitename>" and you are running this command from that directory

Comment: 'directory structure' - hint was enough :).  Stupid mistake - I was not changing my dir to django project. Adding cd <path-to-django-project> before manage.py solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake - I was not changing my dir to django project. Adding `cd <path-to-django-project>` before `manage.py` solved the issue.

Final setup commands:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
cd <path-to-django-project>
python manage.py runserver --noinput
tar -czf release-backend.tgz .*
```